# Pickle username/score EOF error Python

Tags: python, pickle

I am very new and I apologize for what may be asking a question with a simple answer that I am missing, but I have spent 3 hours trying to get this snippet of code to work in conjunction with a larger program and I am running out of hair to pull out. I keep getting an EOFError

```
score = 12

def scor_func(score):
  scores = []
  name = input("Please enter your name: ")
  entry = (name, score)
  scores.append(entry)
  f = open("Triviascores.bat", "wb+")
  pickle.dump(scores, f)

  scores = pickle.load(f)
  f.close()
  return scores

scor_func(score)
```

Comment: could you paste the error itself (i.e. whole traceback)?

Comment: Okay, warning. I do have some code commented out above it.
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/storage/emulated/0/programming/pickletest.py", line 35, in <module> scor_func(score)
  File "/storage/emulated/0/programming/pickletest.py", line 31, in scor_func 
  scores = pickle.load(f)
EOFError

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  Your use of `input` implies Python 3, please confirm.

Comment: I am using Python 3. But it is "Python for Android"

I have had no issues using these same types of code before, so I honestly am not sure why this code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close the file after the `dump` then open it again before the `load`:

```
import pickle

score = 12

def scor_func(score):
  scores = []
  name = input("Please enter your name: ")
  entry = (name, score)
  scores.append(entry)
  f = open("Triviascores.bat", "wb")
  pickle.dump(scores, f)

  f.close()

  f = open("Triviascores.bat", "rb")
  scores = pickle.load(f)
  f.close()
  return scores

scor_func(score)
```

If you need to store then retrieve an object immediately, you might be better off with a `shelve`, which is part of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `close` file to flush and close data stream.

```
  f = open("Triviascores.bat", "wb+")
  pickle.dump(scores, f)
  f.close()

  f = open("Triviascores.bat", "r")
  scores = pickle.load(f)
  f.close()
```